# Multiple nullable Guid and only one of them can have a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a FinancialAccount Class that can be linked into three other classes, or manually generated , So I implemented one Enum holding the the type of class that its linked to and three other nullable Guid's to hold the Guid of that linked class

```
public enum AccountClassificaiton
{
    Normal,
    Bank,
    Contract,
    Employee,
}

public Account()
{
    ...
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AccountClassificaiton AccountClassificaiton { get; set; }
    public Guid? ContractId { get; set; }
    public Guid? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Guid? BankAccountId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I need a better approach for this problem considering that i cant move these Guids out of this class , and there is a relation of one to one between this class and those three classes , and only one of these Guid should have a value depending on what AccountClassification this class has

Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker

## Edit-1

Im using a Domain-Driven-Design pattern with 8 projects on the same solution so its not easy for me to show you the real problem without having a legal problem

## Edit-2

This project is a part of Financial Management system which is a part of a huge ERP system

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) in your model, with a "table-per-hierarchy" approach, using the `AccountClassification` as the discriminator column.

Comment: What's the problem ? If it's the constraint enforce it at the db. However this really does point to larger schema design smell.. you really need to point to what the actual issue is

Comment: (1) *"I need a better approach for this problem"* What is the *problem* and what is bad with the shown approach in order to need *better*? (2) *"considering that i **cant** move these Guids out of this **class**"* If you can't move fields out of the class, I don't see what you can do. Some proposed TPH inheritance, but there the fields will be in the same *table*, but in different *classes* than this (which will be the base).

Comment: I don' t see any problem here, everything is fine.  the only thing I would never use is enumeratiion. Create a special table instead of it if it is not very late yet.

Comment: i just didnt like the idea of having multiple nullable guids , and thanks for every one who proposed TPH (Table per Hierarchy) approach i didnt know something like that existed, im a bit new to the C#-EF-core so im still learning , i cant reveal the whole code due to an NDA that i signed,

Comment: I'm very Open to any other approach , since it very useful for me to learn different stuff and try to come with the best solution

Comment: "i just didnt like the idea of having multiple nullable guids" What do you like then? You can move them in a special table but what you are going to win? 10 bytes  of each records  but you will have to mantain very confused and tricky  database shema  and application code.

Comment: Showing real problem does not mean showing real code. Just a sample code which shows the real problem. So far, other that the clarification in the comments that you don't like having 3 nullable Guids in the table I see no actual problem. You can use TPH, but the table still will have these 3 nullable guids. Or you can use TPT (which eliminates the need of `AccountClassificaiton` field/column, and now you'll have 3 more tables with 1 GUID in each + PK, which in general would waste much more space. The only benefit would be a bit cleaner design.

Comment: Both inheritance strategies are explained in the official EFC docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I would design it differently:

```
public enum AccountClassificaiton
{
    Normal,
    Bank,
    Contract,
    Employee,
}

public Account()
{
    ...
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AccountClassificaiton AccountClassificaiton { get; set; }
    public List<Account> LinkedAccounts { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Something like that.

Or, even better in case you need to find linked accounts fast by the account type, you can use a Dictionary where the key is the AccountClassificaiton type (value is the Account object) to group the linked accounts by type:

```
public Dictionnary<AccountClassificaiton, Account> LinkedAccounts { get; set; }
```

Of course you can indent the dictionary to get better searching efficiency in case you have many linked accounts:

```
public Dictionnary<AccountClassificaiton, Dictionnary<Guid, Account>> LinkedAccounts { get; set; }
```

Or use a custom equality comparer treating Guid and AccountClassificaiton kind of a composite key:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-5.0